# How to store MongoDB database config information in a web application?

Tags: mongodb, servlets, glassfish

While using relational databases like `MySQL`, we can create a `JNDI` resource in `GlassFish` server(which I am using) and then use it as `DataSource` by looking up the context.

**Is there an equivalent way for doing this for `MongoDB` in `GlassFish`?**

If no then what is the best way to store the connection details like DB username and password for **MongoDB** without hard-coding them into the application or having some kind of properties files inside the web application from where we access the connections details?

I am using a Java Servlet as my web technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an alias in glassfish for your password and access it by calling `System.getProperty("mypassword")`

Comment: I solved it by creating a JNDI custom resource and then calling it via the `InitialContext` object reference.